# How can I turn a multi-page TIF file into a PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, tiff

I have a large multi-page TIF image file.

I scanned in a book a few days ago and I accidentally scanned it as a multi-page TIF. I really want to turn it into a more accessible PDF file.

Do you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: "GIGANTIC" is somehow subjective. You could improve your question, if you give some numbers: Number of pages and size of TIF file (compressed or not) would be a good starting point.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question linked since the two questions are different. In this case the person wishes to convert a multiPAGE TIFF file into a single PDF. In the other the person wants to convert and merge MULTIPLE TIFF files into a single PDF. While related the questions are distinct! Is there a way to mark a question as 'unique'?

Comment: TIFF to PDF converter sites exist online. For example, a quick search brought up: https://tiff2pdf.com/ It successfully converted my 12 page multipage TIFF to a PDF. Apologies for answering in a comment but the question is locked for editing (for now... I'm trying to resurrect it with clarification :).

Answer (score 24):

If you are fine with just converting the file format (without making the text searchable (via OCR as pointed out [in the answer by Jonathan Ben-Avraham](https://superuser.com/a/591656/167207)), this will be a perfect task for `convert` from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) package (available for various platforms: Win, Linux, Mac). When you install, be sure to select the option to include the "convert" legacy utility.

Simply use that command to convert your multi-page TIFF file

```
convert multi-page.tif book.pdf
```

However, you should employ the `-compress` Parameter. If you have a 24bit colored TIF, you can use `LZW` (lossless) or `JPEG` (lossy), e.g.

```
convert -compress LZW multi-page.tif book.pdf
```

If your TIFF is black and white (please make sure, it is really saved with only 1bit colordepth), I usually use `-compress Fax`.

Here is an example for a 5 page sample file, with some text in it -- the actual ratio between the compression algorithms depends of course on the content of your file:

```
24bit JPEG:  1294kB
24bit LZW:   1759kB
1bit  Fax:    135kB
```

After that conversion you still can run a OCR tool (like Adobe Acrobat Pro) to make the text search- and copyable.

Comment: Many thanks for `-compress Fax` flag which is especially useful for book scans.

Comment: I didn't have a convert executable but I did had magick so this is the command I used:  magick convert -compress fax "%1.tif" "%1.pdf"

Answer (score 3):

TIFF (Tagged Image File Format) is a pixel-oriented format that is intended for images. In order to get just the character data from a TIFF file you would have to use an OCR (Optical Chararacter Recognition) program. All OCR programs have some error rate. The format of the pages (header, footers, section headings, etc) also affect the ability of OCR to accurately guess the characters.

The language and particularly the writing system and font also affect OCR accuracy. If the book has an unusual non-western font with ligatures then the chance of getting goot OCR output are close to zero.

If the book is not primarily text, for example, a book with many screen shots or other images that are important, then OCR will not help you.

There are some Open Source OCR programs available, depending on the OS you are using. Google Drive has a free OCR service. WMMV.

Assuming that the original book you scanned is in paper format, then TIFF is about the best you can do in any event. You can make the document size more manageable by compressing the TIFF file. Try JPEG compression with various levels of compression to optimize document size against readability.